# Vuexfire {serialize} option not formatting array properly

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex, vuefire, vuexfire

I am trying to add all Firestore document Ids when I query a collection. I can query all collections in an instance, but cannot tie their document Ids to the collection arrays.

This is the code I have that works to query all a user's products within a vuex file called product.js

```js
import { firestoreAction } from 'vuexfire'
import { db } from '@/firebase/init'

const state = {
  products: []
}

const getters = {}

const actions = {
  init: firestoreAction( context  => {
    const allProducts = db.collection(`users/${context.rootState.authentication.user.uid}/products`)
    context.bindFirestoreRef(
      'products',
      allProducts, { 
        wait: true, 
        serialize: doc => {
          // console.log(doc.id) -returns the IDS I am looking for
          return Object.defineProperty(doc.data(), 'id', {
            value: doc.id
          })
        }
      }
    )
  })
}
```

I then get this data

```js
[
   {
      "name":"product1"
   },
   {
      "name":"product2"
   }
]
```

I am looking to get data to pass to vuex like this:

```js
[
   {
      "id":"kmp1Ue8g0I130XZ3Ttqd",
      "name":"ll"
   },
   {
      "id":"qswtcdmnxNxbwmPNR1S3",
      "name":"fdsfs"
   }
]
```

The above ids show up when I use `console.log(doc.id)`, but I don't get the expected array with ***id*** values, just product ***name***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you cannot modify the Object returned by `doc.data()`.

The following, using the object spread operator to create a new plain object, should do the trick:

```
return {
   id: doc.id,
   ...doc.data()
 }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much